# Gliders on a Rubik's Cube

Tags: geometry, combinatorial-geometry, rubiks-cube

This question is bugging me for a long while:

Is it possible to turn an *unmodified* 3x3x3 Rubik's Cube into a position where there is a [Glider pattern (from Conway's Life)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glider_(Conway%27s_Life)) on every side of the cube?

How many different solutions are there if we only care of the relative position of the gliders but not their colors? What are these?

(Being unmodified is important because it is possible to disassemble and then reassemble a cube so that it can't be solved again with standard turning moves. So reassembling a cube to a form matching my requirements doesn't count as a solution in itself.)

Comment: It is not even obviously clear to me that merely disassembling the cube can make gliders on every face. (Peeling off the stickers will of course do the trick).

Comment: Also, are both the odd and the even phases of the glider (on different faces) acceptable?

Comment: You can google "rubik's cube solver", and draw it there. Keep in mind that many such solvers let you draw colours freely. You should take care to at least draw a cube that can be assembled from the parts of a single original cube (keeping in mind edge and corner pieces, for instance).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes.

Comment: @Arthur That's a great idea! However, drawing all possibilities in itself doesn't seem trivial, and quite frankly, I'd love to see an exhaustive mathematical solution (at least a computer assisted one) to this :)

Answer (score 3):

My Rubik's cube says it's possible:

[image]

Comment: wass the maths in it ?

Comment: I just used $(L^2U^2)^3$ and $(M^2U)^6$ until every face had a glider on it.